How to use ASP.NET Core attribute routing to get full path after endpoint name
I am very new to routing in ASP.NET Core.
The system I am prototyping has strings with associated names like:

/dev/accounting/people = "people string"
/test/it/documents = "some it document string"
/some/arbitrary/name/separated/by/slashes = "some other string"

much like a dictionary. What I want is to make an endpoint in my API that would be accessed like:

http://mysite/api/GetString/dev/accounting/people
http://mysite/api/GetString/test/it/documents
http://mysite/api/GetString/some/arbitrary/name/separated/by/slashes

I have this so far
Dictionary<string, string> _stringDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "/abc", "this works" },
    { "/abc/def", "this doesn't" },
    { "/abc/def/ghi", "neither does this" },
    { "/some/arbitrary/name/separated/by/slashes", "nor this"},
};

[Route("api/GetString/{objectPath}")]
[HttpOptions]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetString(string objectPath)
{
    // -http://mysite/api/GetString/abc this works
    // -http://mysite/api/GetString/abc?param1=2&param2=3 this does too
    // -http://mysite/api/GetString/abc/def nope
    // -http://mysite/api/GetString/some/arbitrary/name/separated/by/slashes?param1=2&param2=3 nope
    // I want objectPath to be everything after 'getstring' in the URLs above EXCEPT the parameters

    string resultValue = "[[NOT FOUND]]";

    if (_stringDictionary.ContainsKey(objectPath))
        resultValue = _stringDictionary[objectPath];

    return new OkObjectResult(new 
                              { 
                                  result = resultValue,
                              });
}

Obviously, this is a routing problem. I have been able to get one or two parameters in the GetString method to work, but I get 404's when specifying more. Clearly I'm doing something wrong, and it may very well be that what I am asking for is impossible.

https://asp.mvc-tutorial.com/routing/routing-templates/
The solution turned out to be to use a '*' character in front of the token, like this:
[Route("api/GetString/{*objectPath}")]

I don't get the leading slash, but that's fine, I can prepend that before the search. Of course, after 3 hours of searching, I find this 17 minutes after posting the question :-)
Best regards and HTH someone
